# computing lpNorm column wise in Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

When I try to call `lpNorm<1>` with `colwise()` in Eigen I get the error:

> error: 'Eigen::DenseBase > >::ColwiseReturnType' has no member named 'lpNorm'

Instead norm() and squaredNorm() work fine calling them colwise.

example

```
  #include <Eigen/Dense>
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;
  using namespace Eigen;
  int main()
  {
    MatrixXf m(2,2), n(2,2);
    m << 1,-2,
      -3,4;
    cout << "m.colwise().squaredNorm() = " << m.colwise().squaredNorm() << endl;
    cout << "m.lpNorm<1>() = " << m.lpNorm<1>() << endl;
 //  cout << "m.colwise().lpNorm<1>() = " << m.colwise().lpNorm<1>() << endl;
}
```

works fine giving

```
m.colwise().squaredNorm() = 10 20
m.lpNorm<1>() = 10
```

If I uncomment the last line I get the error.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not implemented for `colwise` in Eigen <=3.2.9. You have two options:

1. Upgrade to [Eigen 3.3](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=3.3) (beta)
2. Loop over all columns and calculate the lp norms one by one.

Comment: As I thought. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may by-pass it that way:

```
m.cwiseAbs().colwise().sum()
```

Unfortunately it only works in case of L1 norm (which is equivalent of an absolute value).